# visualize a document field in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need help to generate a visualization. A term in one of my document indicies, 'temperature', is not in the drop down box of fields to visualize in kibana. What must I change so that 'temperature' shows up as a field in the drop down?

Situation:

- ES 5.1
- Dynamic Templates
- The field is present a portion of documents
- The index mapping interprets the field as a 'long'

In Discover, Kibana can filter the documents shows a table of "temperature" and "timestamp." I seek help to visualize the data shown in that table.

A filtered search for the term in the console yields a search result with documents.

```
GET /_search
{
    "size" : 10,
    "_source": ["temperature", "timestamp" ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "name" : "HomeThermostat" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to visualize let's say a date histogram, where the X-Axis is the *timestamp* and Y-Axis is a numeric field (in your case: *temperature*) , then you would have to choose the following settings from the drop down:

**For X-Axis**

1. Aggregation = Date Histogram
2. field = timestamp
3. Interval = Choose your desired interval

**For Y-Axis**

1. Aggregation = Median (median of a single value is the value itself)
2. field = temperature

If your drop down does not show the field `temperature` then a possible reason is that `temperature` is not being recognized as a numeric value.

Go to `Management -> Index Patterns -> your index` and check whether the field `temperature` is saved as a number or not.

Comment: The index pattern tip is very helpful. While I set the index mappings up correct, the index patterns had the prior patterns. After resetting the pattern Kibana generates the visualization I seek.